# Time segment lost when I try to retrieve Date and time from SQL Database

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database

[image: Data from mssql]

This is what the Datetime data look like in the database

when I try to retrieve the data in my Android app, I use the following code

```
 DateTime createDateTime = new DateTime(dataset.getDate("createDateTime"));

Log.d("Time I get is",createDateTime.toString());
```

at the end it only manage to return

```
2015-12-16T00:00:00.000+08:00
```

in my datalog, my time become 00:00

How can I retrieve the time too?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dateTime = sdf.format(dataset.getDate("createDateTime"));
Log.d("Time I get is", dateTime);
```

You can also try:

```
dataset.getTimestamp("createDateTime");
```

Comment: THANKS, I use dataset.getTimestamp("createDateTime"); problem solved!!